# Access X axis of the chart and Set interval between labels dynamically

Tags: c#, word-interop

I have a template document that contains a chart.[image]

Using this template i generate a report.

It works fine when i have certain number of values, 7 in given example. but when the sample data increases the category axis looks clustered, As shown.

[image]

I would like to Dynamically set **interval between labels** to either automatic or specify the interval using formula, but i am unable to access this property.

[image]

I tried googling this but didn't help.
I would appreciate if anybody could help me with this.

Comment: if my answer could help you, dont forget to validate and/or upvote..its the way to say "thank" toe th communauty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have tested a solution and seems ok:

before test my word file:

see [Axis Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.axis.ticklabelspacingisauto?view=word-pia)

[image]

my code:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
:
:
    private void WordWithExcel()
    {
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Word.Application application = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document wordDoc = application.Documents.Add(@"d:\+test3.docx");

        //i suppose there is only one inline -> always begin by 1 dunno why
        Word.InlineShape shape = wordDoc.InlineShapes[1];
        Word.Chart chart = shape.Chart;

        var axis = chart.Axes(Word.XlAxisType.xlCategory);
        axis.TickLabelSpacingIsAuto = false;

        // if you want modify the spacing value
        // axis.TickLabelSpacing = 2;

        object filename = @"d:\++t.docx";
        wordDoc.SaveAs2(ref filename);
        wordDoc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    }
```

and the result:

[image]